# Slack no longer shows red dot when someone sent me message

Tags: mac, slack

I recently had to get a new computer (mac - not M1) and I installed slack, it used to be when someone had messaged me in slack that I would see a red dot on the icon down in the task bar but now I don't see the red dot.

I suppose there is some setting I can turn on to get this visual notification back because it is really useful if I turn off sound or I wander off to get a coffee for a few minutes.

Comment: Things have moved around in prefs on Big Sur, but afaik it's still in Notifications prefs - "Badge app icon"

Comment: thanks found it, it's a danish mac so it is under systemudstillinger / meddelser, and messages from slack were turned off. in Slack preferences/notifications there is a show a badge on slack's icon to indicate new activity.

Comment: Do you want to put that in as an answer - i can't provide a picture, don't have a Mac running Big Sur

Comment: Ok I will put it in an answer.

Answer (score 43):

thanks to Tetsujin I found the Mac settings that related to it

This would be in Mac Settings -> Notifications, of course in my system which is in Danish is it Systemudstillinger -> meddelser but the same stuff.

[image]

above a screenshot of my danish system with the messages turned on. The text will of course change for another language.

However this is not the only thing that applies to the notification icon being on.

There is also settings in Slack, in Slack if you go to Preferences (which you get to by clicking your workspace), the notifications panel should be shown, you will probably have to scroll down to see the part that says:

Sound & appearance
Choose how notifications look, sound, and behave.

under that there will be a checkbox with the label "Show a badge A dock badge on Mac on Slack's icon to indicate new activity", you have to have that selected.

Comment: Confirmed works with M2 and Ventura, thanks for this, missed a few OS upgrades!